# Null pointer exception in creating a dialog in quickblox

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, quickblox

I having some issue in creating a dialog of type group in quickblox chat service on android. I am able to get all the user from the server side of quickblox, able to build dialog and adding those users i got in it but when it comes to call groupChatManager.createDialog(dialog, new QBEntityCallbackImpl(). I am getting a null pointer exception on that. I found later that i have to initialise chatService in class that extends application i did that but still same error. here is my code

```
enter code here
My applicationSingeltonClass
public class ApplicationSingleton extends Application
{

private QBUser currentUser;
//quickBlox
private static final String APP_ID = "key";
private static final String AUTH_KEY = "authkey";
private static final String AUTH_SECRET = "authsec";
private static ApplicationSingleton instance;
private Map<Integer, QBUser> dialogsUsers = new HashMap<Integer, QBUser>();
private QBRoomChat currentRoom;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{

    super.onCreate();
    initApplication();
    initImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
}
public static ApplicationSingleton getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}
private void initImageLoader(Context context)
{
    // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them,
    // or you can create default configuration by
    //  ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
    // method.
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
            .build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}


public QBUser getCurrentUser()
{

    return currentUser;
}

public void setCurrentUser(QBUser currentUser)

{
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
}

public Map<Integer, QBUser> getDialogsUsers()

{
    return dialogsUsers;
}

public void setDialogsUsers(List<QBUser> setUsers)
{
    dialogsUsers.clear();

    for (QBUser user : setUsers)
    {
        dialogsUsers.put(user.getId(), user);
    }
}

public void addDialogsUsers(List<QBUser> newUsers)
{
    for (QBUser user : newUsers)
    {
        dialogsUsers.put(user.getId(), user);
    }
}

public Integer getOpponentIDForPrivateDialog(QBDialog dialog)
{
    Integer opponentID = -1;
    for(Integer userID : dialog.getOccupants())
    {
        if(userID != getCurrentUser().getId())
        {
            opponentID = userID;
            break;
        }
    }

    return opponentID;
}
private void initApplication()
{
    instance = this;
    QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true);
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY,AUTH_SECRET);

}
```

}

here is my other class were i create a dialog

```
enter code here

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)
    {
        if(status.equals("accepted"))
        {

            pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
            pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(10);
            final ArrayList<String> usersLogins = new ArrayList<String>();
            usersLogins.add(userID);
            usersLogins.add(herocivID);
            final ArrayList<Integer> occupantIdsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            occupantIdsList.add(civID);
            occupantIdsList.add(heroCivID);

            QBUsers.getUsersByFacebookId(usersLogins, pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle params)
                {

                    if (!QBChatService.isInitialized())
                    {
                        QBChatService.init(getApplicationContext());
                        chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                        chatService.addConnectionListener(chatConnectionListener);
                    }


                    QBDialog dialog = new QBDialog();
                    dialog.setName("chat with mostafa wo may");
                    dialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
                    dialog.setOccupantsIds(occupantIdsList);

                    QBGroupChatManager groupChatManager = chatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager();
                    groupChatManager.createDialog(dialog, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args)
                        {
                            Log.i("", "dialog: " + dialog);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "you accepted the request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(status.equals("rejected"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "you rejected the request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

i need to know were exactly i have to configure the chat service to prevent the null pointer while creating a dialog.
Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue.
First you need to check roomChatManager if its equal to null you have to ask the user to login in.
Second in the login wether your using social provider or by mail you have to login to chatService ( ApplicationSingleton.getInstance().chatService.login(userResult);)
ApplicationSingleton is a java class were it extends Application in it you initialise the ChatService.
Thats it now you can create your dialog successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You're right,

```
chatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager();
```

is null if you're not logged in ti Chat

so you have to login to chat first and then call this method